# What should I use instead of .__getslice__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm in the process of porting a library to Python 3. I found this method:

```
def __getslice__(self, index, listget=list.__getslice__):
    self._resolve()
    return listget(self, index)
```

which raises an error since `.__getslice__` is deprecated. I looked at the documentation and it seems like `.__getitem__` is what most people are using to replace `.__getslice__`. The only issue is that this library has a method exactly like the above method except it's called `__getitem__` and `listget=list.__getitem__`). I can't tell why they made this distinction in the code, but it seems like the original designers of the library wanted to preserve the unique functionality of both methods. Is there any way I can keep to this while porting over to Python 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to simply delete the `__getslice__` method all together.  Now (in python3.x) `__getitem__` handles the same cases that `__getslice__` used to handle in addition to the cases that `__getitem__` handled -- SO, in python3, the `__getslice__` method on the custom class (perhaps a list subclass by the looks of it) should never be called.

Also note that if this is a list subclass, then you should use `super` to call the superclass:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    self._resolve()
    return super().__getitem__(index)
```