# Python getslice Item Operator Override Function not working

Tags: python, class, oop, operators

Practicing the examples posted [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Classes) for learning Python OOP. Am looking for the output of '1 to 4', but instead it throws the error below.

```
class FakeList:
     def __getslice___(self,start,end):
         return str(start) + " to " + str(end)

f = FakeList()

f[1:4]
```

Note: Using `f.__getitem__(1, 4)` results in the correct output--"1 to 4", as shown in the link above.

> Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 f[1:4]
>
> TypeError: 'FakeList' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What's the Python version?

Comment: Don't use `__getslice__`, it has been deprecated long back and removed in Python 3. Use `__getitem__`, it supports slice objects.

Comment: [What should I use instead of .__getslice__?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27850161/2301450)

Comment: Using '__getitem__' in place of still results in an error.

Comment: When using "getitem" the new error reads: "TypeError: __getitem__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'end'"

Comment: that is because the `__getitem__` **and `__getslice__`** only take a single argument (a slice object)

Comment: From [Python Data model](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html) "Slice objects are used to represent slices for [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) methods. They are also created by the built-in [slice()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#slice) function."

Comment: Using `f.__getitem__(1, 4)` results in the correct output. However, the question relates to how to use slice in place of `f[1:4]` (e.g., with a slice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the `__getitem__` method takes one parameter of `slice` type, and you can access start/end of the range via `slice.start` and `slice.stop`, here is an example with some more debug output to show what is going on:

```
class FakeList:

    def __getitem__(self, slice_):
         print('slice_', slice_)
         print('type(slice_)', type(slice_))
         print('dir(slice_)', dir(slice_))
         return str(slice_.start) + " to " + str(slice_.stop)

f = FakeList()

print(f[1:4])
```

The output:

```
slice_ slice(1, 4, None)

type(slice_) <class 'slice'>

dir(slice_) ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__',
'__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__',
'__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__',
'__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__',
'__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'indices', 'start', 'step', 'stop']

1 to 4
```