# how to override slicing in python

Tags: python, collections, slice

I'm posting this question because I did not find a clear answer anywhere else.

Consider the following python code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List


@dataclass
class ShoppingItem:

    name: str
    price: float


@dataclass
class ShoppingCart:

    items: List[ShoppingItem]
    discount: float = field(default=0)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.items.sort(key=lambda item: item.price)

    def total_price(self):
        return (1 - self.discount) * sum(item.price for item in self.items)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.items[key]
```

Using the square brackets operator, one can get a specific item from the shopping cart.

```py
cart = ShoppingCart(
    items=[
        ShoppingItem(name="Shirt", price=100),
        ShoppingItem(name="Pants", price=120),
        ShoppingItem(name="Socks", price=40),
        ShoppingItem(name="Shoes", price=80),
    ]
)
print(cart[1])  # Will print Shoes
```

Now, let's consider that we want to take a subset of the shopping cart using the slicing operator (because we want to take only the 3 most expensive items), but we want the output to be a `ShoppingCart` (because we want to keep the discount). If we use the implementation above, the result object will be a `list`, not a `ShoppingCart`:

```py
most_expensive = cart[-3:]  # returns a list, not a ShoppingCart
```

How can I override the slicing operator to return a `ShoppingCart` but keep the simple square brackets operator to return the `ShoppingItem`?

Answer (score 0):

While in Python 2.7 there were the `__getslice__` magic method for overriding slicing specifically, in Python 3 this method was deprecated and only `__getitem__` is being used.

Therefore, when overriding the square brackets operator, one can check if the input is a `slice` object, and then make sure that the returned item is as expected. In our example, it should look like that:

```py
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, slice):
        return ShoppingCart(items=self.items[key], discount=self.discount)
    return self.items[key]
```

Comment: If your class is so close to being a subclass of list, you could do that and then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27850325/2237151) solution to access a slice.

Comment: You're right for this "simple" example, but in my original problem it wasn't possible :)